# Is there any country that does not use English for publishing?

Tags: language, developing-countries

In my country, all the literature and medium of instruction, pertaining to research, is in English only.

Due to less proficiency of earlier generations in English and several other linguistic reasons, comprehension of research literature is difficult for current generation(s).

I am wondering whether there is any country that does not use English and uses its own language for publishing all its scientific literature?

Comment: "all its ..." is too strong. I think a lot of countries publish "some" of its scientific literature in their national languages. France, Germany, ... But science is aided when most scholars speak a common language. Latin...English... whatever. You probably want to increase your proficiency.

Comment: I agree with @Buffy, "_all its_" is too strong… But in some fields, and some countries, there are attempts to use "native to the country" languages. For instance, [JFLA](http://jfla.inria.fr/) publishes contribution in Computer Science _only in French_, but it's clearly the exception, not the rule.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/56007/20058

Comment: I'd say it also depends on the field. Some knowledge is clearly of local interest (local social studies, regional economy analysis or maybe geological findings) or heavily connected to local culture (literature, poetry, language phenomena). So perhaps it's natural to expect local language proficiency from an interested reader.

Comment: @rg_software linguistics and literature are also obvious candidates.